# Upper bound on $n\choose t$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

How can we show that ${n\choose{t}} < (\frac{ne}{t})^t$? I think Stirlings Approximation should help, but I can't figure out the computation to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We prove this inequality by induction on $k$, where $k \leq n$. For $k=1$ is trivial. Suppose that inequality holds for $k-1$. Now we would like to show that is true for $k$. \ Since $\binom{n}{k}= \binom{n}{k-1} \cdot (\frac{n-k
+1}{k})$, then by hypothesis we have:
\begin{equation}
\binom{n}{k}= \binom{n}{k-1} \cdot (\frac{n-k+1}{k})<(\frac{ne}{k-1})^{k-1}\cdot (\frac{n-k+1}{k}).
\end{equation} 
Hence, we just need to show:
\begin{equation}
(\frac{ne}{k-1})^{k-1}\cdot (\frac{n-k+1}{k}) < (\frac{ne}{k})^k,  (1)
\end{equation}
After rearranging (1) we have:
\begin{equation}
(\frac{ne}{k-1})^{k-1} \cdot (\frac{k}{n})^k \cdot\frac{n-k+1}{k} < e^k.  (2)
\end{equation} 
After simplifying (2) we have:
\begin{equation}
(1+\frac{1}{k-1})^{k-1} \cdot \frac{n-k+1}{n} < e.   (3)
\end{equation} 
And (3) is true, because $(1+\frac{1}{k-1})^{k-1} < e$ for all $k>1$, and trivially inequality $\frac{n-k+1}{n}\leq 1$ is true for all $k \leq n.$\